# Sharing Rules on Activities

Tags: activities, sharing-rule, owd

OWD as follows

[image]

A user in the role of 'Customer Support Agent' should be able to view Activities related to Accounts and Contacts they do not own.

Since Sharing Rule on Activities is not possible.
What other options are out there to explore ?

Comment: You'll have to set manual sharing rules on the account so the role can view the tasks linked to the account.